# How to evaluate numbers on a list in an individual manner?

Tags: python, list, math, logging

For example, I have a list of numbers:

```
du = 0.001
u = [0]
for i in range(1, 500):
    u.append(round(u[i - 1] + du, 3))
n_strain = [0]
for i in range(1, 3):
    n_strain.append((400 / 0.002) * u[i])
for i in range(4, 500):
    n_strain.append(400)
```

and I want to define another function X as the ln of the values on the **n_strain** list
for that I do math.log() but it only evaluates individual values

`X = [math.log(j) for j in n_strain[i] for i in range(500)]`

won't work, I've tried. This could be applied to other examples, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got how to do it. First, I was overcomplicating thing with math, is a list, so apparently is better to do it with numpy, after having a simple list, all I had to do was use np.log and that's it. This was the code:

```
du = 0.001

u = [0]
for i in range(1, 501):
    u.append(round(u[i - 1] + du, 3))

n_strain = [0]
for i in range(1, 3):
    n_strain.append((400 / 0.002) * u[i])
for i in range(3, 501):
    n_strain.append(400)

X = np.array(n_strain)
z = [1]
for i in range(1, 501):
    z.append(1)
Z = np.array(z)
Y = Z + X

t_strain = np.log10(Y)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have just made a small mistake. Here are two ways, you can use.

```
X = []
for st in n_strain:
    val = math.log(st)
    X.append(val)
```

or if you want by list comprehension

```
X = [math.log(st) for st in n_strain]
```

Comment: hmmm, I tried both now but it gives me the "ValueError: math domain error" error